# Microservice running inside docker container(on EC2 instance) is not reaching AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

I am trying to add AWS  Application load balancer in front of Microservices(Running on EC2 node inside VPC and public subnet). Those are running inside docker container. I noticed that, If microservice is running on directly on EC2 instance. It able to communicate with ALB. When started microservice inside a docker container. It is not communicate with  ALB.

I am able to reproduce with curl:

1) Hit curl directly on EC2 instance - Working

```
  $ curl  http://vpc-elb-url/alive
```

Response:

```
 ok
```

2) Hit curl from inside docker container  - not working

```
$ docker run --rm byrnedo/alpine-curl  http://vpc-elb-url/alive
```

Response:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1120  100  1120    0     0  65882      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 65882
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Not Found</title>
        <style>
            html, body, pre {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: Monaco, 'Lucida Console', monospace;
                background: #ECECEC;
            }
            h1 {
                margin: 0;
                background: #AD632A;
                padding: 20px 45px;
                color: #fff;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                border-bottom: 1px solid #9F5805;
                font-size: 28px;
            }
            p#detail {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 15px 45px;
                background: #F6A960;
                border-top: 4px solid #D29052;
                color: #733512;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3);
                font-size: 14px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #BA7F5B;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
        <p id="detail">
            For request 'GET /alive'
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a valid question. I am answering this, maybe it will help other. If somebody doing the same mistake:(

We are routing all traffic from 80 to 9000 using this command:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9000
```

Because this ALB becomes unreachable. We simply removed this rule using below command

```
sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9000
```

Everything is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the container is not sharing the same AIM role with the EC2 instance

There is a project called IAM-docker that shares the host IAM role with the container (you can read about how it works in the repo)

In addition it lets you manage what container will get what access

https://github.com/swipely/iam-docker